# NSIS -- Read and execute section mention in a setup.ini file

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm new to use NSIS, to create installer.
I want help as below

**Structure of setup.ini:** 

    `; section titles
    [setup]
    sec0=my first section
   sec1=my second section
    sec2=my third section`

**Nsis script structure**

   `;Sections
    Section 'sec0'
  ; ...
  SectionEnd
  Section 'sec1'
  ; ...
  SectionEnd
 Section 'sec2'
  ; ...
  SectionEnd`

Here I'm looking that, if I'm not including "sec1=my second section" in setup.ini file, then Installer should skip this and not install. Means installer should read setup.ini first, then install only section mentioned there.
Please let me know, how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section 'sec0'
SectionEnd

Section 'sec1' SID_1
SectionEnd

Section 'sec2'
SectionEnd

!macro SetSectionFromAnswer inient sid
ReadIniStr $0 "$exedir\Setup.ini" "setup" "${inient}"
${If} $0 == "" 
 !insertmacro UnselectSection ${sid} 
${EndIf} 
!macroend

Function .onInit
!insertmacro SetSectionFromAnswer "sid1"  ${SID_1}
FunctionEnd
```

When using a answer file like this, I would recommend that instead of checking if the entry not present, you should check that it is `!= "0"`. This way the installer will function normally even if the .ini does not exist.

Comment: Hi Anders, I tried this in my script.. but getting error. that "Function .onInit" already exists. Because I already have ".onInit" defined. How to use multiple .onInit functions?? Also what this sid_1, ${sid}, ${SID_1} is doing. My requirement is if I'm not defining a section name in Setup.ini file, the installer should skip that section and should not install.

Comment: There can only be one init function but you can just add my line to your existing function. "sid1" is the name to look for in the ini file and SID_1 is the NSIS numeric section ID.